# Laravel routing to controller - routing to wrong route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a very strange bug.
Running Laravel 4.1 as my company hasn't upgraded their PHP version yet.

The routes file has this:

```
Route::controller('survey', 'SurveyController');
```

And, when you go to /survey/new-survey it ends up being sent to postNewQuestion function instead of postNewSurvey.

```
public function postNewSurvey() {
    $input = Input::all();
    //dd($input);
    $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required|unique:lime_surveys_languagesettings,surveyls_title',
        'language' => 'required'
    );
...... etc
}
public function postNewQuestion() {
    $input = Input::all();

    //dd($input);

    $rules = array(
        'sid' => 'required',
        'gid' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'question' => 'required',
        'mandatory' => 'required',
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return Response::json(array('success' => false, 'error' => 'validation',
            'messages' => $validator->messages(), 'failed' => $validator->failed()));
    }
......... etc
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are you running this url. From form? If yes, show the form code.

Comment: It is a http request from Angular. The url is:

url: 'surveys/add-survey'

Comment: And why it's not `survey/new-survey` ? Looking at your question, you should POST to this url

Comment: It is posting to 'survey/new-survey'

Comment: Above is the correct url it is posting to.

Comment: I think there is an error in code you haven't showed us, so it will be difficult to help you

Comment: Yes there was. It was late on a Friday and I wasn't thinking properly. Thanks.